# Motor shield code

Tags: arduino-motor-shield, code-review

I am working on a project using an Arduino Uno and a motor driver shield to move a car with an IRremote. But the vehicle is only moving forward and backward. I want it to move left and right. Kindly help.

This is the code:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <AFMotor.h>
AF_DCMotor rightMotor(3); // Right motor connected to port 3
AF_DCMotor leftMotor(4); // Left motor connected to port 4
IRrecv irrecv(11);
decode_results results;
#define Straight 0x1FED827
#define Right 0x1FE708F
#define Left 0x1FE30CF
#define Back 0x1FEF00F
#define brake 0x1FE48B7

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) { 
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    switch (results.value) {
    case Straight:
      moveForward();
      break;
    case Right:
      turnRight();
      break;
    case Left:
      turnLeft();
      break;
    case Back:
      moveBackward();
      break;
    case brake:
      Stop();
    }
    irrecv.resume();
  }
  delay(100);
}

void moveForward() {
  leftMotor.setSpeed(200);
  rightMotor.setSpeed(200);
  leftMotor.run(FORWARD);
  rightMotor.run(FORWARD);
}

void turnRight(){
  leftMotor.setSpeed(200);
  rightMotor.setSpeed(200);
  leftMotor.run(FORWARD);
  rightMotor.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(400);
  leftMotor.run(FORWARD);
  rightMotor.run(FORWARD);      
} 

void turnLeft() {
  leftMotor.setSpeed(200);
  rightMotor.setSpeed(200);
  leftMotor.run(BACKWARD);
  rightMotor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(400);
  leftMotor.run(FORWARD);
  rightMotor.run(FORWARD);
}  

void moveBackward() {
  leftMotor.setSpeed(200);
  rightMotor.setSpeed(200);
  leftMotor.run(BACKWARD);
  rightMotor.run(BACKWARD);
}

void Stop(){
  leftMotor.setSpeed(0);
  rightMotor.setSpeed(0);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is it that you don't receive the code, that the car doesn't steer, that the motors stop working, ...? Moreover I'd highly suggest you not to use delays, but.. whatever

Comment: You need to check if the Right and Left vars are defined correctly. Use serial monitor to show exaclty the value sent when you try to turn right or left.

Comment: the power that the motor sheild is providing to the motor in insufficient and the car is not moving.but it making a noise and the serial monitor is giving the correct hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: kindly help !!!!!

Comment: @SwathiM Sorry but... If you already discovered that "the power that the motor sheild is providing to the motor in insufficient", why are you asking help about the code? Do you think that changing some variables you will be able to move it? First of all let it move, then try to control it. If with a simple "move forward" sketch it doesn't work it's a setup problem. Check the batteries (empty batteries do not have the power to move the motors), check the motor voltage rating (you can't move a 24V motor with 4 AA batteries = 6V), ...